# Curl with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl

I'm using the following code to execute a rest API using Curl with Node.JS. It is working on my local machine.

```
...
...
var child_process = require('child_process');

    function runCmd(cmd)
    {
        var resp = child_process.execSync(cmd);
        var result = resp.toString('UTF8');
        return result;
    }

    var cmd = "curl -u userx:passx -X POST --data @test.json -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://mysite.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/";
    var result = runCmd(cmd);
...
...
```

But after uploading to server, I'm getting the following error

```
/home/ubuntu/PMPBuild/jiraIssue.js:76
                var resp = child_process.execSync(cmd);
                                         ^
TypeError: Object function (command /*, options, callback */) {
  var file, args, options, callback;
```

Comment: What version of Node are you running? I ran this exact script, with the just the URL and got a response

Comment: I can show you how to use `node-curl` library if you can't get this working, just let me know

Comment: I'm using the version v0.12.10

Comment: node.js v0.12.10 is way, way out of date.  You should be running either 4.x or 6.x (preferably 6.x)..

Comment: @NextLocal please show me how to use node-curl

Comment: @jfriend00 I updated the version to 6.x and now it is working. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your server is not supported CURL. It will better if you use a request library https://github.com/request/request

```
var request = require('request');
var jsonData;

fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('test.json', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
});

request({
    url: 'https://mysite.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/',
    'auth': {
     'user': 'userx',
     'pass': 'passx',
     'sendImmediately': false
    },
    qs: jsonData,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}, function(error, response, body){
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(response.statusCode, body);
    }
});
```

Comment: I use request. It's great

Comment: The OP is using CURL for a POST, with JSON data with a username and password.  Your answer does not show how to do all that with the `request()` library which is the operative part of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Simple example with [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.httpbin.org', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }
})
```

Example on how to use [node-libcurl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-libcurl)

```
var Curl = require('node-libcurl').Curl;
var curl = new Curl();
curl.setOpt( Curl.option.URL, 'http://www.httpbin.org');
curl.setOpt( Curl.option.FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl.setOpt( Curl.option.HTTPPOST, [
    { name: 'login', contents: 'username' }
]);
curl.perform();
```